# Retrieving image from firebase shows same image multiple times

Tags: android, firebase, imageview, firebase-storage

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private static final int RC_PHOTO_PICKER = 2;
    private String mUsername;

    // Firebase instance variables
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mMessagesDatabaseReference;
    private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
    private FirebaseStorage mFirebaseStorage;
    private StorageReference mChatPhotosStorageReference;
    private FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemoteConfig;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;

    PhotosAdapter contactsAdapter;
    List<Photos> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        floatingActionButton=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.floatingactionbutton);
        contactList = new ArrayList();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Initialize Firebase components
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();


        mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages");
        mChatPhotosStorageReference = mFirebaseStorage.getReference().child("chat_photos");

        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    onSignedInInitialize(user.getDisplayName());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    onSignedOutCleanup();
                    startActivityForResult(
                            AuthUI.getInstance()
                                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                    .setProviders(
                                            AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER,
                                            AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER)
                                    .build(),
                            RC_SIGN_IN);
                }
            }
        };




        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);

            }
        });


        mMessagesDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Photos imageUploadInfo = postSnapshot.getValue(Photos.class);
                    if(!contactList.contains(imageUploadInfo)){
                        contactList.add(imageUploadInfo);
                        Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: "+contactList);
                    }

                }

                contactsAdapter=new PhotosAdapter(contactList,getApplicationContext());
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(contactsAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {



            }
        });

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),5));
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Sign-in succeeded, set up the UI
                Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Sign in was canceled by the user, finish the activity
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }else if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            // Get a reference to store file at chat_photos/<FILENAME>
            StorageReference photoRef = mChatPhotosStorageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

            // Upload file to Firebase Storage
            photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
                          //  progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                            // Set the download URL to the message box, so that the user can send it to the database
                            Photos friendlyMessage = new Photos(downloadUrl.toString());
                            mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mAuthStateListener != null) {
            mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
        }
    }

    private void onSignedInInitialize(String username) {
        mUsername = username;

    }

    private void onSignedOutCleanup() {
        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;

    }
}
```

Suppose I upload an image to firebase storage, it gets retrieved in my imageview of recyclerview in app. When I upload second image, the first image gets displayed twice and second image once in my app. When I upload third image, first image gets displayed thrice, second image twice and third image once. I know the problem is in  `mMessagesDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener` but I am not able to figure it out. Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that `onDataChange` will be called with all data at each new upload. So you have to clear `contactList` before adding items, like:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    contactList.clear()

    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
        Photos imageUploadInfo = postSnapshot.getValue(Photos.class);
        if(!contactList.contains(imageUploadInfo)){
            contactList.add(imageUploadInfo);
            Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: "+contactList);
        }
    }

    contactsAdapter=new PhotosAdapter(contactList,getApplicationContext());
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(contactsAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `ChildEventListener` instead of `value event listener`. 
Value event listener fetches all the data again on a single change so for adding image 2, image 1 will also be received in value event. 
In `ChildEventListener` there is method `onChildAdded()` where you add to your recycler.

Use the child event listener like this, no need of for loop, it will be called for when a child is added, avoiding need to do a loop

also after adding item don't forget to call notify on recyclerAdapter to show changes on view

Move these in onCreate method and intialize there:

```
contactList = new ArrayList();
contactsAdapter=new PhotosAdapter(contactList,getApplicationContext());

recyclerView.setAdapter(contactsAdapter);
```

**Code to get child from firebase**

```
private void attachDatabaseReadListener() {
        if (mChildEventListener == null) {
            mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        Photos imageUploadInfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(Photos.class);
                        if (!contactList.contains(imageUploadInfo)) {
                            contactList.add(imageUploadInfo);
                        }

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            }
            mMessagesDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEvent‌​Listener);
        }
    }
```

Comment: private void attachDatabaseReadListener() {if (mChildEventListener == null) {mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
Photos imageUploadInfo = postSnapshot.getValue(Photos.class);
if(!contactList.contains(imageUploadInfo)){
contactList.add(imageUploadInfo);}
}}  mMessagesDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener); } }

Comment: The image does not get added in my app

Comment: see my changes in answer